# grunt connect port option ignored

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-connect

I am unable to get grunt connect to use the port that I specify in the options. 
In my grunt file is the following configuration

```
connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            hostname: '0.0.0.0'
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                port: 9001,
                open: true,
                base: 'test'
            }
        }
    }
```

However when I run `grunt connect:test` the console raises returns the following

Opening server for /home/peter/Projects/HammerHead2 on port 1337.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple solution

I had install grunt-connect NOT grunt-contrib-connect

Comment: +1 billions. That was my mistake too. Spent 2 days desperately trying every gruntfile-configuration I could find on the internet... Problem is, grunt doesnt even complains, and happily ignores the config. Thank you sir.