# What is the difference between grunt-connect and grunt-contrib-connect?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect, grunt-connect

I've seen problems stem from confusing `grunt-connect` and `grunt-contrib-connect`(See *[grunt connect port option ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765074/grunt-connect-port-option-ignored/24765175#24765175)* and  *[grunt watch & connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836478/grunt-watch-connect)*)

Given their similarity and conflicting natures, could someone describe their syntactical differences, as well as any functional differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`grunt-connect`](https://github.com/iammerrick/grunt-connect)

- For when you want to run a server indefinitely, for example on a web server (note: this is not what grunt is intended for, instead use grunt to process files, then something like [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) or apache HTTP server, to host the processed files).

[`grunt-contrib-connect`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect)

- When you want to start a web server for *other grunt tasks* to use.

[`grunt-serve`](https://github.com/lud2k/grunt-serve)

- This is similar to `grunt-connect` and is what I use in [my projects](https://github.com/harrymt/harrymt.github.io/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L103).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer.